# IBM Watson Document Conversion not working at all

Tags: ibm-watson, document-conversion

We recently implemented the Document Conversion API from IBM Watson. 
We always get the error, even though we specify the document type:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type - The media type of the input file is not supported. Specify the MIME type of the document if auto-detection was not correct.
```

We are trying to convert PDF's to plain text. Even the sample PDF from IBM didn't work for us.

Comment: Both the demo and the service itself are working well for me, can you please give more detail?  What sort of file are you trying to convert, and what is your conversion target type?

Comment: @catbelly I just noticed that the demo just doesn't work in Safari. But the service still isn't working. I'm trying to convert a simple PDF to plain text (tried it with the IBM sample PDF as well).

Comment: @OSX55 are you passing the MIME type as suggested in the error?

Comment: @OSX55 can you paste the call you are making exactly?